# Small Core Data performance gains from background saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, performance, core-data

I'm trying to squeeze every last performance gain from my app's use of Core Data. Using a large data set for testing, I've made some significant gains by refactoring the object graph and modifying various predicates used in fetching. The only thing I'm still not pleased with, in terms of performance, is saving the context after a large delete operation. As a result, I finally implemented threading using a parent-child context structure. However, I am underwhelmed by the performance gain.

**Object graph:** I'm only showing the relationships because I know that's what makes deleting expensive.

Country:

- cookingStyles (to-many relationship)

CookingStyle:

- country (inverse relationship, one-to-one)
- recipes (to-many relationship)

Recipe:

- cookingStyle (inverse relationship, one-to-one)

For the sake of argument, assume that each cooking style is unique for a country. Therefore, configuring the `CookingStyle`'s `country` relationship as one-to-many will NOT de-duplicate data. The same goes for each recipe, i.e., each recipe is unique for a cooking style.

**Performance Test:**

*Data set:* 18 Country objects, each `Country` has 10 `CookingStyle` objects, each `CookingStyle` has 35 `Recipe` objects (total = 18 `Country` objects, 180 `CookingStyle` objects, 6,300 `Recipe` objects)

I'm using Time Profiler to measure performance on a 5G iPod Touch running iOS 7.1.

I'm using parent-child `NSManagedObjectContext` instances to implement threading.

The table view controller where the deletion occurs uses a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

*Results:* Saving the parent-child contexts after deleting one `Country` object still takes about 1000 ms. Prior to implementing threading, it took about 1200-1300 ms to delete a `Country` object.

When I dive deeper into the Time Profiler results, saving from the child context to the parent context is blocking the main thread. The latter save is not hitting the disk, so I assumed that it would be faster.

**Question:**

Are my expectations too high under the test case, or is there something else I should be doing to improve performance when deleting `Country` objects?

**Code:**

How I create the parent-child contexts:

```
_model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
_coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_model];

_parentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [_parentContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_coordinator];
    [_parentContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
}];

_context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_context setParentContext:_parentContext];
[_context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
```

How I save the contexts (source: "Core Data", 2nd Ed., Marcus Zarra):

```
- (void)saveContext:(BOOL)wait
{
    if (!self.context) return;

    if ([self.context hasChanges]) {

        [self.context performBlockAndWait:^{

            NSError *error;
            if ([self.context save:&error]) {
                QuietLog(@"\nchild context SAVED changes to parent context");
            } else {
                QuietLog(@"\nchild context FAILED to save: %@", error);
                [self showValidationError:error];
            }
        }];
    }

    void (^saveParentContext)(void) = ^{

        NSError *error= nil;
        if ([self.parentContext save:&error]) {
            QuietLog(@"\nparent context SAVED changes to persistent store");
        } else {
            QuietLog(@"\nparent context FAILED to save: %@", error);
            [self showValidationError:error];
        }
    };

    if ([self.parentContext hasChanges]) {

        if (wait) {
            [self.parentContext performBlockAndWait:saveParentContext];
        } else {
            [self.parentContext performBlock:saveParentContext];
        }
    }
}
```

How I delete and save:

```
- (void)deleteButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    AEBCoreDataHelper *coreDataHelper = [AEBCoreDataHelper sharedCoreDataHelper];

    Country *country = ...

    [coreDataHelper.context deleteObject:country];

    // NSFetchedResultsController's delegate will delete the row for me

    [coreDataHelper saveContext:NO]; // blocks main thread for too long  
}
```

**Update:**

I thought it was the UI that was unresponsive while the parent-child contexts were saved. It's not. Instead, anything involving Core Data is unresponsive until the parent context (private queue) completes its save to the disk. The UI only seemed unresponsive because I tried to scroll the table view, which requires another batch of data from the fetched results controller. If I scroll through the entire table view before deleting an object, then scrolling is responsive soon after deleting. Multi-threading with Core Data feels like shenanigans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are blocking on saving the parent if the parent has changes but not blocking when it doesn't have changes.  That is not going to gain you any performance.

If you don't have changes, there is nothing to save, it is effectively a no-opt.

If you have changes, you want them to run asynchronously so that your main thread can go back to servicing the user. There is no value in blocking the main thread as the main context already knows about the changes and anything it changes will not impact the save.

Lastly, using a private context will not be "faster".  It will give a perception of being faster to the user because they get control back sooner.  Threading is not directly linked to performance.  The idea of offloading the save is so that the user can go back to using the app instead of waiting for the save.  The save can easily take longer but the user doesn't care.

### Update

If you are getting the UI blocked on a scroll then that is an indication that your save is taking too long.

**ANY** activity that hits the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is going to lock it.  A long fetch or a long save, doesn't matter.  This is a fact of life.  There are ways to avoid that rule but just throwing threads at the problem is not going to fix it.  You need to work with the underlying issue of locking the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

First, I would look at breaking up the save into smaller units.  Making the saves smaller allows the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to weave in saves and fetches so that the human doesn't perceive the saves.

If you can't do that, consider doing your deletes against a separate `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  This is assuming you are using SQLite.  You can then feed the changes back to your main `NSManagedObjectContext` via notifications.  Note that the consumption of those notifications will cause a performance impact on the main `NSManagedObjectContext` and therefore on the UX.

You can also explore pre-faulting in the objects in the `UITableView` so that there is no need to go back out to disk.  But then you are trading speed/performance for memory and on iOS you tend to lose when you do that.

Comment: He means that you are calling: `[self.context performBlockAndWait:` when you should be calling: `[self.context performBlock:`